# Why does justify-content-center center contents of a row but not a container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Why does this center the contents

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
   <h2>Some heading</h2><br>
</div>
```

But this doesn't?

```
<div class="container justify-content-center">
   <h2>Some heading</h2><br>
</div>
```

(they are exactly the same but for `row` in the first code and `container` in the second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Flexbox.  `container` has not been declared as a flexbox object so it cannot take advantage of placement classes like `justify-content-center`.

The `row` class however, looks like this:

```
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Because it's display has been modified to use Flexbox it (and its children) can benefit from Flexbox-dependent utility classes.

Comment: Interesting. Is there an easy way to work out which bootstrap classes are Flexbox and which aren’t?

Comment: The Bootstrap Documentation has a complete list of all of their Flexbox utility classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/